# Script Shell - Command nohup - "&" - Doubts

Tags: shell

I don't exactly know What this Next line does:

Command Line:

```
nohup java -Dprocess=$PROCESS -classpath $CLASSPATH batch_wtq &
```

I mean i have a little idea about -NOHUP- command but i don't know what the ampersand (&) does.
I would like someone help me with a description about the whole command line.

Comment: The ampersand at the end of the line makes the command run in the background. I don't know about `nohup` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nohup` means "no hangup", meaning that the process will still run after you log out of the shell.  The amptersand `&` means the process will run in the background and so you'll get back to your shell prompt after you run that command.

The `-Dprocess` is a Java property being passed in to the Java program with the environment variable `PROCESS`.  Likewise, the classpath is being set to the environment variable `CLASSPATH`.  The Java class with the `public static void main` method is `batch_wtq`, which should be on the classpath somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Eric Finn.